# Pyspark DF: How to add literal empty dict '{}' column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have json files where each line is a json object w/ a number of strings and one dict.
`{"str_a":"blah","str_b":"blah","dict_obj":{}}`

The dict object is usually `"dict_obj":{}`, occasionally contains values, and rarely is missing from all json lines, like:

```
{"str_a":"blah","str_b":"blah"}
{"str_a":"blah","str_b":"blah"}
{"str_a":"blah","str_b":"blah"}
```

I want to ensure this field is present in the json output. If I add an empty column, then the printout looks like: `{"dict_object":null}`
However, if a single record in a batch contains the `"dict_obj":{}` field, then the saved json contains `"dict_obj":{}`.

Things I have tried so far that result in `"dict_obj":null`:

```py
df.withColumn("dict_object", F.lit(None))

df.withColumn("dict_object",
    F.lit(None).cast(MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
)

df.withColumn("dict_object",
    F.lit(None).cast(StructType([StructField("", StringType(), True)]))
)
```

How can I replicate that field so the output contains `"dict_obj":{}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `create_map` function like this:

```py
from pyspark.functions import F
df = spark.range(1).withColumn("x", F.create_map())
```

```
>>> df.show()
+---+---+
| id|  x|
+---+---+
|  0| []|
+---+---+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- x: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
```