# Pyspark add empty literal map of type string

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67793996/pyspark-df-how-to-add-literal-empty-dict-column) I want to add a column to my pyspark DataFrame containing nothing but an empty map. If I use the suggested answer from that question, however, the type of the map is `<null,null>`, unlike in the answer posted there.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map
spark.range(1).withColumn("test", create_map()).printSchema()

root
 |-- test: map(nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: null
 |    |-- value: null (valueContainsNull = false)
```

I need an empty `<string,string>` map. I can do it in Scala like so:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit
spark.range(1).withColumn("test", typedLit(Map[String, String]())).printSchema()

root
 |-- test: map(nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

How can I do it in pyspark? I am using Spark 3.01 with underlying Scala 2.12 on Databricks Runtime 7.3 LTS. I need the `<string,string>` map because otherwise I can't save my Dataframe to parquet:

```
AnalysisException: Parquet data source does not support map<null,null> data type.;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast the map to the appropriate type creating the map using `create_map`.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map
spark.range(1).withColumn("test", create_map().cast("map<string,string>")).printSchema()

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- test: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```